# Error with writing and transferring files with Dropbox and Python

Tags: python, dropbox

I am trying to send a number that I input on one computer to another computer to print out. I am trying to do this using python to read and write the files and I am trying to use Dropbox to create a server so I can access the same file on two different computers.

Here is my sending code:

```
def seeInput():
    print("enter num")
    inp=input("")
    r=open(r"C:\Users\\Desktop\Dropbox\test.txt", "w")
    r.write(inp)
    r.close()
    seeInput()
seeInput()
```

Here is my receiving code:

```
global i
i=0
blank_list=[]
def getRes():
    r=open(r"C:\Users\\Desktop\Dropbox\test.txt", 'r')
    out=r.read()
    r.close()
    return out
while True:
    coolString=getRes()
    blank_list.append(coolString)
    before=blank_list[i-1]
    now=blank_list[i]
    i=i+1
    if now != before:
        print (coolString)
```

I expected this code to output the number I entered on the other computer.

But instead, the Python IDLE gave me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\Dropbox\receive.py", line 10, in <module>
    coolString=getRes()
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\Dropbox\receive.py", line 5, in getRes
    r=open(r"C:\Users\\Desktop\Dropbox\test.txt", 'r')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\\\Desktop\\Dropbox\\test.txt'
```

It would be great if someone could help me because I am very new to all of this server stuff.

Comment: Path has one `\\` too much.

Comment: I am not 100% sure as there is about a year since I did this last, but I seem to recall that I was unable to open/edit/stream files in the Dropbox directory. It seem that the Dropbox daemon/program keeps these files under a type of watch that locks them. I _could_ be wrong, but I seem to recall this. Additionally, this was only a problem on Windows platforms, macOS and Linux worked fine. Edit: Once you fix your path you should be able to test this by turning off the Dropbox program.

Comment: So, if I wanted to input something into a windows machine and have it output into a Linux machine using these same technologies, it would work. Right?

Comment: Also, the path has too many backslashes because I had the name of my system there and I would not like to share that information with anyone who wants to see it.

Comment: @JoeShanahan Yes, I think that I was able to do this on macOS and Linux systems, but the Windows platform had some issues. Did you verify my theory by turning off the Dropbox program and run your code again?

Comment: I am not really sure how to do that, like should I run them then turn it off or turn it off then run them?

Comment: Also, how would I go about turning it off?